# Issue with `float: left;`

Tags: html, css

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcV2v/).

Essentially, I have two divs which have `float: left;` and are separated by a `<br/>`. The problem is that the `div`s appear one next to the other, instead of displaying one below the other, with a space in between.

Comment: That's how floated elements work. If you want them to appear one below the other why did you float them?

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Comment: why do you need the float:left;? works ok without if you put a max-width on them you should be fine

Comment: The reason I use "float: left" is so that the blue border it a "tight fit" with the text (no whitespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `clear: left`, and you can use `margin-bottom:1em` to give the gap in-between if you like. http://jsfiddle.net/zn5wA/1/

With `float:left` the `<br>` will just appear next to the elements that are floating.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish for them to appear beneath each other, don't use `float:left;`

http://jsfiddle.net/XcV2v/2/

Alternatively, you can use `clear:both`, but if you have no use for `float:left`, then it would be simpler to remove this

Comment: The reason I use "float: left" is so that the blue border it a "tight fit" with the text (no whitespace).

Comment: Ah okay, in that case you can use `clear:both` to force the div beneath one another :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear them.

Add `clear:both;`

```
.container {
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px blue;
    clear:both;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XcV2v/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the first float first to put another float.

following could help you:

```
<div id='div1' style=float:left>
....
</div>

<div style=clear:left></div>

<div id='div2' style=float:left>
...
</div>
```